# Python: Add elements to dictionary attribute of class not works

Tags: python

I' trying to create a class containing a dictionary as attribute, and methods to add elements to the dictionary and to show all the elements that the dictionary contains. 
So I tried this:

```
class Catalogue:
    def __init__(self):    
        self.dictionary = dict()

    def addElement(self,name,price):
       if(self.dictionary.has_key(name)):
            print "This item is already in the catalogue. "
       else:
            print "The item ", name , "was added to the catalogue"
            self.dictionary[name] = price         

    def showElements(self):
        print "CATALOGUE: "
        print self.dictionary
```

And then when used this class inside main function, addElements() doesn't work properly

```
catalogue = Catalogue

item  = raw_input("Name of the item: ")
price = raw_input("Price: ")

catalogue().addElement(item, price)

catalogue().showElements()
```

For example if I put as item= "CD" , and price = "1" 
The outputs of those methods are:

From catalogue().addElements(item,price)

```
 The item CD was added to the catalogue
 {'CD', '1'}
```

But then when I used catalogue().showElements()

```
 CATALOGUE:
 {}
```

It seems that dictionary is not passed by reference in the method addElements.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check how to instantiate a class and call a method?

Answer (score 3):

Your class definition is fine, it is just the way you are using it. Each time you write `catalogue()`, you are creating and accessing a new `Catalogue` instance, so each line is acting on a *completely separate object*.

This line:

```
catalogue = Catalogue
```

assigns the `Catalogue` class to the name `catalogue`, it *doesn't* create an instance. Instead, use:

```
catalogue = Catalogue()
                   # ^ important!
```

to create a new instance of the class `Catalogue`, and assign *that instance* to the name `catalogue`.

Now you can use that instance, e.g.:

```
catalogue.addElement(item, price)
       # ^ no parentheses here
catalogue.showElements()
       # ^ or here
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not creating or calling methods the class correctly

If you add in a print statement right after you call this

```
catalogue = Catalogue
print catalogue
```

You will see this

```
__main__.Catalogue
```

This is because you actually made `catalogue` a reference to your class `Catalogue`. You need to change it to this to call your constructor instead so that you create an instance of a `Catalogue` object.

```
catalogue = Catalogue()
```

Calling the class name with the parantheses calls the default constructor.

And then when you call the methods, you are creating new Catalogue objects each time because you're using the parentheses again

```
catalogue().addElement(item, price)
```

You need to call methods on your object like this (no parentheses)

```
catalogue.addElement(item, price)
```

If any of this is unclear, I recommend the following reading

[Python docs on Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

[Intro to Modules, Classes, and Objects](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html)

[Guide to Speaking Object Oriented](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex41.html)

[Is-A, Has-A, Objects, and Classes](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex42.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how classes and instances work. Every time you call `catalogue()` you get a *new* instance: that's what the parentheses do, they call the class which constructs a new instance.

Instead of doing `catalogue = Catalogue` and then `catalogue().addElement` you should be doing:

```
catalogue = Catalogue() 
catalogue.addElement(item, price)
catalogue.showElements()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the catalogue variable:

```
catalogue = Catalogue
```

You don't construct a catalogue object, you just create a variable `catalogue` that is a reference to the `Catalogue` class, so when you try to access your functions, you're really creating two new catalogue objects that don't share any values:

```
catalogue().addElement(item, price) # this constructs a catalogue object

catalogue().showElements() # so does this
```

To fix this, just change your assignment to a constructor

```
catalogue = Catalogue()

catalogue.addElement(item, price) # this is now reference to above object
catalogue.showElements() # so is this
```